# Proceed If File Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, io

I have the following code:

```
public static void readtext(string pathtoText)
{

    if (File.Exists(pathtoText))
    {   
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathtoText);

        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            clearPath(line);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} doesn't exist, or isn't a valid text file", pathtoText);
    }
}

public static void clearPath(string path)
{

    if(Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Length;

        if(directoryCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has Subdirectories to Remove", path);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                dir.Delete(true); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has no directories to remove", path);
        }

        int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;

        if (fileCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has files to Remove", path);

            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                try
                {
                    file.Delete(); 
                }
                catch(System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Close the following File {0}", file.Name);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Path Doesn't Exist {0}", path);
    }
}
```

My function reads directories from a text file and passes it to clearPath which checks if the directory exists, and if so, cleans it. My problem is that, if a directory doesn't exist,  it stops the program(it doesn't move to the next directory to check if it exists and clean, the for each loop just stops) .

How do I get it to the next directory even if specific directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you missing the argument 0 in the final Console.WriteLine? What do you mean with _it stops the program_?

Comment: Can you post the code for `clearPath` please ?

Comment: @Jaco - The problem is in the foreach loop, clearPath method posted.

Comment: Can you comment out this line in your clearPath method and see how it goes: Console.WriteLine("Path Doesn't Exist {0}", path);

Comment: @Batuta - Same issue. Would the continue statement in the for each loop work?

Comment: @EmmaGeller-Green - I'd recommend learning how to use your debugging tools and step through the code until it goes awry.

Comment: @EmmaGeller-Green Can you put a try catch block on your clearPath method so that you can see what the exception is being generated? Then just put a breakpoint while in debug on the catch(Exception) line. Its probably going into an endless loop.

Comment: The code is most likely failing because you have invalid directory paths in your files. This would throw an exception you are currently not catching.

Comment: @Jaco - Using continue worked. I print out if a directory doesn't exist, however, I want the program to move on to the next directory in the text file, continue in the for each did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible that you have empty lines in your file?

you can try something like that:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
      clearPath(line.trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try calling the function one by one, and passing each path it works, however, when I use a foreach loop, if the path to the directory doesn't exist, it stops right there, I want it to move forward even if a directory doesn't exist. I used the continue keyword in the foreach loop and it worked, is that the recommended way to do it?

Comment: can you share an example of input file and console output that you are getting?